# How to test the serialisation of a transaction?

Tags: transaction, cardano-serialization-lib, decentralized-applications, emurgo, bytes

When using the Cardano serialisation library by emurgo, how do you test the output works as intended? Would this change when using parameterised contracts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using an API service like BlockFrost https://blockfrost.io/ you can utilise the Transaction output (cborHex) string from the completed Serialization Library build process by copying it into an existing Cardano-Cli Signed Transaction and submit it via the Cli.

Signed Cli Transaction Format for file *tx_1.signed*:

```
{
    "type": "Tx AlonzoEra",
    "description": "",
    "cborHex": "<insert the cborHex string created by the serialization-lib here and submit via cli command"
}
```

Cli Command format for testnet

```
cardano-cli transaction submit --tx-file /Users/someuser/cardano-src/*tx_1.signed* --testnet-magic 1097911063
```

There is also a simple boolean function for testing if the Transaction is valid:

```
pub fn is_valid(&self) -> bool {
        self.is_valid.clone()
    }
```

https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/blob/master/rust/src/lib.rs

Hope this helps.